# Using JS to connect to an API and then output the JSON response

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to do a UK Postcode validation using JS by connecting to http://postcodes.io/ post code validation service.

When I post to **api.postcodes.io/postcodes/POSTCODEVARIABLE/validate** I should recieve a 200 response and result of either "True" or "False" depending on whether the postcode is valid or not.

However, when I try to receive the data (in JSON format) I get an error in the console:

```
 "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1"
```

Here is my code, if anyone could point out where I am going wrong, that would be great.

```
var cpostcode = 'RG1 8BT';
var cpostcode = cpostcode.replace(/\s+/g, '');
var myNewURL = 'https://api.postcodes.io/postcodes/' + cpostcode + '/validate';

var pcapi = new XMLHttpRequest();


pcapi.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (pcapi.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
    alert(pcapi.responseText);
    }
}

pcapi.open("GET", myNewURL, true);
pcapi.send(null);

var xyz = JSON.parse(pcapi);

console.log(xyz);
```

Comment: You are not parsing the result, but the `XMLHttpRequest` object.

Comment: Just updated the script.

Answer (score 1):

Like at @Youssef said you want to log the `.responseText`. You get that script error because `pcapi` is a `XMLHttpRequest` object and not valid json which `JSON.parse()` attempts to parse. If you want to learn more about what you can do with the `pcapi` object just `console.log(pcapi)` and you can see its `{keys:values}` or just [read](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/dom_httprequest.asp) up on it.

> JSON.parse() converts any JSON String passed into the function, to a JSON Object.
>
> There is really no such thing as a "JSON Object". The JSON spec is a syntax for encoding data as a string. ... JSON is a subset of the object literal notation of JavaScript. In other words, valid JSON is also valid JavaScript object literal notation but not necessarily the other way around. - [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation)

```js
var cpostcode = 'RG1 8BT';
var cpostcode = cpostcode.replace(/\s+/g, '');
var pcapi = new XMLHttpRequest();

var myNewURL = 'https://api.postcodes.io/postcodes/' + cpostcode + '/validate';

pcapi.open("GET", myNewURL, false);
pcapi.send();

var xyz = JSON.parse(pcapi.responseText);

console.log(xyz);
```